# Can't update Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, updates

I'm trying to do the last updates of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & this window is always shown.

[image]

Ubuntu is never able to update the OS.

I tried: `$ sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 64.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.173.1 [64.6 MB]
Fetched 64.6 MB in 6s (10.4 MB/s)
```

and i tried: `$ sudo apt-get update`

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                    
Get:3 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,591 B]            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Hit:5 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                 
E: Repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Opera Software ASA' to 'Opera Software AS'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

and:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install --> not working.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/64.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

Anybody know a solution?

Comment: What does synaptic show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual problem lies here

```
E: Repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Opera Software ASA' to 'Opera Software AS' 
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

Run `sudo apt update` instead of `sudo apt-get update` and you'll get a prompt to either accept or reject to receive updates from this repository.

Comment: No, after a certain time ubuntu ask me for partial update. Now, after that, no wi-fi adapter found. No more internet. Now i'm trying to fugure what was happen.

Comment: @Hexxefir Have you executed the above command before doing that partial upgrade? Which packages were updated? Which wifi adapter you are using? You might like to ask a new question with the details. :-)

Comment: Ubuntu update did that for me, but i had to reinstall my wifi driver. Your answer was right.